# Change the default blog post post attribute template name from "default template" to something else

Tags: posts, filters, page-attributes

I have found this filter which allows me to change the default name but this changes it for pages and posts. I just want to change it for posts. Is this possible?

```
add_filter('default_page_template_title', function() {
    return __('new default name for posts only', 'your_text_domain');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and one way is by accessing the global `$post` variable and then check if it's for a post of the `post` type (or any custom post types). E.g.

```php
add_filter( 'default_page_template_title', function ( $label ) {
    global $post;
    if ( 'post' === get_post_type( $post ) ) {
        return __( 'new default name for posts only', 'your_text_domain' );
    }

    return $label;
} );
```

Or the other way is by checking if the current screen's ID is `edit-post` (or `edit-<post type>`), and you'd just need to change the above `if` condition to:

```
if ( 'edit-post' === get_current_screen()->id )
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you :), and sorry I was focused on `wp-admin/edit.php` - on the `post-new.php` and `post.php` pages, the screen ID is `post` (or `a_post_type`, i.e. the post type slug).